# How to get the color of the shadow in the different blending mode?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers, blend-modes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get the equivalent of a color in different blending modes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8415/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-equivalent-of-a-color-in-different-blending-modes)

I have an inner shadow effect applied to a shape with blending mode **multiply**. How to get the color of that shadow, if the blending mode was to be **normal** *(only for this layer)*?

Answer (score 0):

Is the shape a flat colour or a gradient with a subtle difference between the start and end? If yes, set the blending to normal and 100% opacity, and use the colour picker to grab the colour from the other object (the one with multiply).

If things are different, then we'll probably need more information and examples to be able to help.

Comment: Yeah Gradient is used